# What is the benefit of using WebSphere MQ classes for Java rather than JMS?

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, ibm-mq

I need to write simple Java client for IBM MQ. What is the benefit using WebSphere MQ classes for Java (`com.ibm.mq.jar`) rather than using WebSphere MQ classes for JMS (`jms.jar`) for writing MQ client in Java?

Comment: Ordinarily I'd vote a question like this down or close it but, as Matt points out in his response, there is actually an authoritative answer for it in this case.  That said, I would highly recommend reading [*What topics can I ask about here?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) in the Help Center for guidance.  Please also see the [tag:websphere-mq] tag wiki for tag-specific guidance and many resources and references.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The IBM KnowledgeCenter has [a short article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q023820_.htm) on this. There is no straight forward "one is better than the other" answer. The main difference between the 2 is the APIs they offer. There's a reasonable argument that you should choose which one to use based on the API you're most comfortable with.

The MQ classes for JMS client implements the [JMS 1.1 specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/docs-136352.html) and (for version 8.0 or later) the JMS 2.0 specification. For the most part this means you can follow non-IBM documentation regarding how to write a good JMS application. There is lots of documentation on the web about JMS so you benefit from a wide range of support from other JMS users.

The MQ classes for Java client is a proprietary IBM API for writing messaging applications that use IBM MQ. It offers an object-oriented equivalent of the procedural MQ API for C and give you access to all of the messaging features available in IBM MQ. Writing an application using the classes for Java exposes you slightly more to MQ specifics. For example to open a queue for putting messages to it you specify the CMQC.MQOO_OUTPUT option, something an MQ developer would be familiar with but a JMS developer would not be. If you're intending to learn about MQ as well as writing a quick sample application the classes for Java might well be better suited to that.

Also because the JMS classes implement an open standard they are not ideally suited to configuring or using all of MQ's proprietary features or configuration options. It is possible set MQ-specific behaviour on the JMS classes, it's just not as well suited to that as the MQ classes for Java.

If all you want is a quick sample client, MQ ships samples for both styles of application:

- For the MQ classes for JMS there are samples in [mq-install-root]/samp/jms/samples (on
  Unix) or [mq-install-root]/Tools/jms/samples (on Windows).
- For the MQ classes for Java the samples are in
  [mq-install-root]/samp/wmqjava/samples (on Unix) or
  [mq-install-root]/Tools/wmqjava/samples